# Java Thread Sockets (PrintWriter & BufferedReader)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a game using only two classes - ServerSocket and Socket. Everything must be at the TCP (not UDP), while architecture is necessarily P2P. The way this game works is that one player chooses a number, then the other and it starts with one of them (no matter which one) counting down. I came across a problem. I establish a connection between two clients and both may enter the selected number. I do not know why I can not send this number to another client. Is the problem that Socket can not send and receive messages at the same time? I've read that there is a possibility to do this using two separate Threads (one receives data, the other sends), but I do not know how exactly.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

    System.out.println("PICK A NUMBER:");
    while (!br.ready()) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    Integer numberGamePicked = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    Thread.sleep(500);
    out.println(numberGamePicked);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    int whatOpponentSend = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine());
    System.out.println("RECEIVED " + whatOpponentSend);
}
```

Of course, up to this point everything is in the run() method. Is the problem that both of them execute the same code at the same time?

Comment: could you give more details? so you open a server socket for one player and a client socket for another player and use the same "run" routine for both? could you post the full code for server and client? It would also be helpful if you post the output messages appearing on both sides when you run it

Comment: it is definitely not related to the fact that they can't send/receive at the same time, however if you use the same "run" for both, the "receiver" will not be able to receive the number sent by "sender" until someone enters a number from keyboard on "receiver" side

Comment: Get rid of those Thread.sleep calls and the br.ready call, they're not doing anything useful for you. The code you've shown only waits for data to be sent from the peer, it doesn't send anything. So, you'll have to show the peer's sending code in order for any debugging to happen here.

Comment: @JamesKPolk but he sends the data using "out.println(numberGamePicked)"

Comment: @mangusta: oh, I missed that, thanks!